# Drag and Drop for React

Tags: reactjs

I've tried React-DND and Dragula, both seem to work in theory but when I try to implement them, I just get stuck even with reading the docs over and over.  Could someone help me out with what seems to be something basic?

I have a component that renders out a list of `players` as a list item in an unordered list. I'd like to be able take a list item and move it into a new unordered list.  I've made my items draggable but am just lost.

Here is my main component *(I've removed Dragula and React-DND out of it for now, I can easily put it back in)*

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Counter from './Counter';
import Titles from '../../../scaffold/titles';
import {players} from './players'


const ScoreList = styled.ul`
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
`

class Counting extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
                  countInfo: []
                  }
    this.incrementCount = this.incrementCount.bind(this)
    this.decrementCount = this.decrementCount.bind(this)
  }

  incrementCount(index) {
    const countInfo = [...this.state.countInfo];
    if(countInfo[index]) {
        countInfo[index].count = countInfo[index].count + 1;
        countInfo[index].nameOf = players[index].name
    }
    else {
       countInfo[index] = {count: 1, nameOf: players[index].name}
    }
    this.setState({
      countInfo
    })
  }

  decrementCount(index) {
    const countInfo = [...this.state.countInfo];
    if(countInfo[index]) {
        countInfo[index].count = countInfo[index].count - 1;
        countInfo[index].nameOf = players[index].name
    }
    else {
       countInfo[index] = {count: -1, nameOf: players[index].name}
    }
    this.setState({
      countInfo
    })
  }


  render() {
    const listPlayers = players.map((players, index) =>
      <Counter
        key={players.id}
        incrementCount={() => this.incrementCount(index)}
        decrementCount={() => this.decrementCount(index)}
        nameof={players.name}
        count={this.state.countInfo[index]? this.state.countInfo[index].count : 0}
      />
  );
    return (
     <div className="wrap">
      <Titles header="Counter" subhead="A setState() project" />
      <ScoreList>{listPlayers}</ScoreList>
      <h3>Drop here</h3>
      <ScoreList></ScoreList>
    </div>
   )
 }
}

export default Counting;
```

And here is the component where the object is created, if I add `draggable=true` to it, it works as far as being able to drag it

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {Icon} from 'react-fa';
import { Row, Col } from 'react-flexbox-grid';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const CountCell = styled.div`
  border: 1px solid #5C57B1;
  background: #6E68C5
  width: 320px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
`

const Score = styled.span`
  color: #74D8FF;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
`
const ScoreName = styled.span`
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 160px;
  text-align: center;
`

const CountButton = styled.button`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  background: #6E68C5;
  height: 30px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  width: 30px;
  transition: all 250ms;
  &:focus {outline:0;}
  &:hover {background: white;}
`


class Counter extends Component {
  incrementCount(e) {
    // I need to update the current state's count, and add 1 to it.
    this.setState({
      count: (this.state.count + 1),
    })
  }

  decrementCount(e) {
    this.setState({
      count: (this.state.count - 1),
    })
  }


  render() {
    const { count } = this.props
    const { decrementCount } = this.props
    const { incrementCount } = this.props
    const { nameof } = this.props

    return (
      <div>
        <CountCell draggable="true">
          <Row style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <Col>
                  <CountButton
                    onClick={incrementCount}>
                    <Icon
                      name="icon" className="fa fa-plus score-icon"
                    />
                  </CountButton>
                </Col>
                <Col >
                  <ScoreName>{nameof}</ScoreName>
                </Col>
                <Col >
                  <Score>{count}</Score>
                </Col>
                <Col>
                  <CountButton
                    onClick={decrementCount}>
                    <Icon
                      name="icon" className="fa fa-minus score-icon"
                    />
                  </CountButton>
                </Col>
              </Row>

        </CountCell>
      </div>


    )
  }
}

Counter.propTypes = {
  // We are going to _require_ a prop called "count". It _has_ to be a Number.
  count: PropTypes.number.isRequired,

  // We are going to _require_ a prop called "incrementCount". It _has_ to be a Function.
  incrementCount: PropTypes.func.isRequired,

  // We are going to _require_ a prop called "decrementCount". It _has_ to be a Function.
  decrementCount: PropTypes.func.isRequired,

  nameof: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}

export default Counter
```

I'm unsure how to get React-DND or Dragula *(or just some basic functions)* to get it to drag into the new `ul`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the target ul like [this](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/examples-nesting-drop-targets.html) or [this](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/blob/master/docs/01%20Top%20Level%20API/DropTarget.md). Basically, make the ul you want to be able to drag into a target for a droppable item and drag and drop it.

Comment: hi @laukCoder thank you for your response.  I some of what's going on in the examples you cited, but when I try to recreate with my project (see above) I can't seem to get my generated `<li>` to drag into another area and am unsure what's going on.  This is what I want to use for drag n drop here https://jabbascrypt.com/projectpages/counter/counting and the code above is what I'm using. 

thanks, I'm just a little confused by this particular plugin